# How to group arrays in multiple loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Using the final `json_encode` I need to output something like this:

```
{ a1: 0, a5: 0, a8: 2, a22: 1, a55: 10, a82: 23 },
{ a1: 3, a5: 5, a8: 3, a22: 2, a55: 0, a82: 2 },
{ a1: 6, a5: 0, a8: 21, a22: 0, a55: 110, a82: 3 }
```

Where respectively the key is the track id (with prefix `a`) and the value is the number of plays, group daily for 3 days.

I tried:

```
$tracklist = "1,5,8,22,55,82";
$tracklist = explode(",",$tracklist);

for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
  foreach($tracklist as $track) {
    $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT `plays`, `tid`
          FROM `views_counts`
          WHERE `tid` = '%s'
          AND DATE(`time`) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s day))", $track, $x));

    $rows = array();

    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

  }
}
```

When there are no plays the query results in empty array.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your query always return only 1 row for each tid?

Comment: @KennethKey if `plays >0` always `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed one foreach because you can do this with a SQL `IN` condition.

```
$tracklist = "1,5,8,22,55,82";
$tracklistArray = explode(',', $tracklist);
$countDays = 3;
$tracksByDay = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < $countDays; $x++) {
    $tracksOfTheDay = [];
    $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT `plays`, `tid`
      FROM `views_counts`
      WHERE `tid` IN(%s)
      AND DATE(`time`) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s day))", $tracklist, $x));

    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tracksOfTheDay['a'.$row['tid']] = $row['plays'];
    }
    foreach($tracklistArray as $tracklistItem) {
        if(!isset($tracksOfTheDay['a'.$tracklistItem])) {
             $tracksOfTheDay['a'.$tracklistItem] = 0;
        }
    }
    $tracksByDay[] = $tracksOfTheDay;
}
$jsonTracks = json_encode($tracksByDay);
```

I updated my answer to have the result with 0, it's a bit ugly to do this stuff php side. You should update your SQL query to have the correct results instead

Please tell me if something is wrong, I hope this will help

Comment: I can't use this, only rows with `plays > 0` are recorded to the database

Comment: I don't understand in which way the asnwer is wrong, please guide me :)

Comment: your answer output something like this `string "[{"a8":"2","a22":"1","a55":"10","a82":"23"},...]"` but it's wrong it should be `string "[{"a1":"0","a5":"0","a8":"2","a22":"1","a55":"10","a82":"23"},...]"`

Comment: Have you got in database a row with id 1 or 5 ? Without that impossible to give you this output. Check your sql data/query

Comment: `tracklist` comes from a different query

Comment: Down, by the way the accepted answer don't follow the basic rules while performing sql queries to database. If you have 300 tracks in your `$trackList` variable, PHP will perform 300 request to database. That's why I use the `IN` condition, with that only 2 requests to database

Comment: I will, thank you very much! ...there is only a problem with the order but in my case it's ok like so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158410/discussion-between-mcsky-and-ninecattorules).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$tracklist = "1,5,8,22,55,82";
$tracklist = explode(",",$tracklist);

$day_group = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
    $current_group = array();
    foreach($tracklist as $track) {
        $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT `plays`, `tid`
                FROM `views_counts`
                WHERE `tid` = '%s'
                AND DATE(`time`) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL %s day))", $track, $x));

        if($query->num_rows === 0) {
            $current_group['a'.$track] = 0;
        } else {
            $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
            $current_group['a'.$row['tid']] = $row['plays'];
        }
    }

    $day_group[] = $current_group;
}

echo json_encode($day_group);
```

Comment: Do more research. There are plenty of similar questions. All the best with whatever you're doing. =)

Comment: I searched a lot, really...but frankly it becomes very difficult when you start to think of thousands of possibilities...you get lost in space!

Comment: I don't like this answer, you do one SQL request for each track returned from the previous query. It's a bad practice to do queries in foreach. Downvote

Comment: @Mcsky well I gave this answer as an example and based on what was provided in the question with least changes so that he can understand one way of doing what he wants to achieve. Provided I have no idea about the use case. It's up to him to explore more on the complexity of the algorithm.